# Why do I get different python version for implicit and explicit localhost

Tags: ansible

I have both python2.7 and python3.7 in my mac and *ansible is installed using python3*. 
Python version and ansible version returns below:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.16
$
$ /usr/bin/env python -V
Python 2.7.16
$
$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.16
$
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.7
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/Users/demo/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/demo/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/demo/Library/Python/3.7/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

Also have an inventory `hosts` with explicit localhost configuration.

```
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

I understand that setting `ansible_python_interpreter` for the inventory will use the specific version but wondering why I get two different python versions for below cases that use either implicit or explicit localhost. My understanding was that for both cases ansible will use the default python version.

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup | grep ansible_python_version
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
        "ansible_python_version": "3.7.3",
$
$ ansible localhost -i hosts -m setup | grep ansible_python_version
[WARNING]: Platform darwin on host localhost is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python
interpreter could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
        "ansible_python_version": "2.7.16",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html)

> when Ansible needs to contact a ‘localhost’ but you did not supply one, we create one for you. This host is defined with specific connection variables equivalent to this in an inventory:
>
> ```
> hosts:
>   localhost:
>     vars:
>       ansible_connection: local
>       ansible_python_interpreter: "{{ansible_playbook_python}}"
> ```

As you can see the implicit localhost declaration is defining an `ansible_python_interpreter` pointing to the one used by the current playbook on the controller (i.e. `ansible_playbook_python` documented in [Ansible special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables))

The explicit localhost definition you posted does not define any and uses [auto-discovery](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html).

Comment: Thanks. Had already gone through theses docs before but doesn’t clearly answer the question. In both the scenarios Python interpreter isn’t declared so I am expecting that the resultant python version should have been the same.

Comment: `ansible_python_interpreter: "{{ansible_playbook_python}}"` => isn't that a declaration?

Comment: I was basically looking for what `ansible_playbook_python` actually mean which wasn't clear to me from the documentation and so this post. However, dug into ansible source a bit and found the details also posted my findings. Thanks for looking into the question.

Comment: This variable is documented in the [special variables page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables).

Answer (score 1):

Just to share what I have found in my investigation on this topic.

**Implicit localhost**

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup | grep ansible_python_version
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
        "ansible_python_version": "3.7.3",
```

It wasn't obvious to me how `ansible_playbook_python` determines python interpreter by looking at [Implicit ‘localhost’](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html) nor [Magic Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic) docs. So poked around ansible source a bit and here is what this variable means.

Value for `ansible_playbook_python` comes from python's `sys.executable` which returns path of the python interpreter that ansible installation is using. In my case, `ansible --version` shows it uses python 3.7.3 so as the return. However, there are cases when `sys.executable` may return nothing ([reference](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13585)) and in that case, ansible would try to fallback to default `/usr/bin/python`.

**Explicit localhost**

```
$ ansible localhost -i hosts -m setup | grep ansible_python_version
[WARNING]: Platform darwin on host localhost is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python
interpreter could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
        "ansible_python_version": "2.7.16",
```

Behavior is quite clear from [interpreter discovery doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html) that ansible uses `/usr/bin/python` by default if available on the host. Otherwise, would try to locate platform specific python interpreter and uses that version. In my case, I already had `/usr/bin/python` of version 2.7.16 so ansible uses that interpreter and so as the return.